# How to use Xander Framework for window forms in c#

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, winforms

I am trying to use xander UI but I can not perform any action.
If I use metroUI then we write in code
class Form1: Metroframework.MetroForms.Forms
in place of class Form1:Forms

Then what can we do for Xander UI?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following steps to use `XanderUI`. It may be different from the `metroUI`.

First, you can download XanderUI.dll from the [XanderUI](https://github.com/Ricky310711/XanderUI). At the end of the article, you can download the dll.

Second, please create a winform app and add a tab in the toolbox.

[image]

Third, please right click the toolbox and select choose Items.

Fourth, choose the download the dll in the choose toolbox item window.

Fifth, you can see the control in the toolbox.

[image]

Finally, you can drag XUIObjectEllipse control first and then drag the XUIFromDesign control.

The following the final result:

[image]